# The bubbles don't appear for some reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The bubbles (white circles) don't appear, here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time
from math import sqrt
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
window = Tk()
window.title('Bubble Blaster')
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='darkblue')
c.pack()
ship_id = c.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15, fill='green')
ship_id2 = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, outline='green')
SHIP_R = 15
MID_X = WIDTH / 2
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2
c.move(ship_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(ship_id2, MID_X, MID_Y)
SHIP_SPD = 10
def move_ship(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, SHIP_SPD)
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        c.move(ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, SHIP_SPD, 0)
c.bind_all('<Key>', move_ship)
bub_id = list()
bub_r = list()
bub_speed = list()
MIN_BUB_R = 10
MAX_BUB_R = 30
MAX_BUB_SPD = 10
GAP = 100
def create_bubble():
    x = WIDTH + GAP
    y = randint(0,HEIGHT)
    r = randint(MIN_BUB_R, MAX_BUB_R)
    id1 = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, outline='white')
    bub_id.append
    bub_r.append(id1)
    bub_speed.append(randint(1, MAX_BUB_SPD))
def move_bubbles():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)):
        c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)
def clean_up_bubs():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
        if x < -GAP:
            del_bubble(i)
def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
        return points
def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y
def del_bubble(i):
    del bub_r[i]
    del bub_speed[i]
    c.delete(bub_id[i])
    del bub_id[1]
def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = get_coords(id1)
    x2, y2 = get_coords(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
c.create_text(50, 30, text='TIME', fill='blue' )
c.create_text(150, 30, text='SCORE', fill='yellow' )
time_text = c.create_text(50, 50, fill='blue' )
score_text = c.create_text(150, 50, fill='yellow' )
def show_score(score):
    c.itemconfig(score_text, text=str(score))
def show_time(time_left):
    c.itemconfig(time_text, text=str(time_left))
BUB_CHANCE = 10
TIME_LIMIT = 30
BONUS_SCORE = 1000
bonus = 0
thend = time() + TIME_LIMIT
score = 0
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while time() < thend:
    chance = randint(1, BUB_CHANCE)
    if chance == 1:
        create_bubble()
        move_bubbles()
        clean_up_bubs()
        score = collision()
    if score == BONUS_SCORE:
        bonus += 1
        end += TIME_LIMIT
    show_time(int(thend - time()))
    show_score(score)
    print(score)
    clean_up_bubs
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y, \
              text='GAME OVER', fill='red', font=('Helevica', 30))
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 30, \
              text='Score: '+ str(score), fill='yellow')
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 45, \
              text='Bonus time: '+ str(bonus*TIME_LIMIT), fill='green')
```

I need help! If you can help me that would be great!
If you want to know the bubbles are white circles drawn with tkinter and python-3.5 with the idle editor, idle doesn't say anything but I know something is wrong because the bubbles (white circles) don't appear. If there is anything wrong with this please let me know.

Comment: You have multiple statements doing **nothing**, e.g. `clean_up_bubs`, `bub_id.append`

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Tkinter is an even-driven GUI framework and nothing happens unless the built-in `mainloop()` is running. It's not like pygame, where you are responsible for writing your own display or game loop.

Comment: @MarquessMark11 ***"It still doesn't work"***: This isn't helpfull. [Edit] your question and show your attempt with: `clean_up_bubs`, `bub_id.append`

Comment: ok can someone show me the code because I don't get really what ye are saying (I am a beginner)

Comment: also for the clean_up_bubs and bub_id.append I removed them if thats ok I don't know really because I am beginner and I am just starting

Answer (score 1):

To call a function, one *must* use parentheses.  A function name evaluates to a function object.  Following parentheses, usually with arguments, then say 'call this function'.

So
    bub_id.append
    bub_r.append(id1)

should be

```
bub_id.append(id1)
bub_r.append(r)
```

With this change, bubbles appear.

Similarly, `cleanup-bubs` should be `cleanup-bubs()`.  This call fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\a\tem3.py", line 97, in <module>
    clean_up_bubs()
  File "F:\Python\a\tem3.py", line 53, in clean_up_bubs
    x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
  File "F:\Python\a\tem3.py", line 65, in get_coords
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'll let you investigate that.

I removed the python-3.5 and python-idle tags as the misbehavior had nothing specifically to do with IDLE or 3.5.

Writing your own event loop with while, sleep, and update is not the best way to use Tkinter.  The app will not respond to events (for instance, key-presses) during sleep. The response to key presses can be as large as the sleep time. Check SO tkinter examples on how to use the mainloop and after methods.

Comment: yeah ok I'll try that also this is my second stackoverflow question

Comment: anyways this is from a book so I will write the code again, I didn't read the instructions only the code